# how to make a auto increment without initializing it as a primary key?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE product( SNo INT AUTO INCREMENT, PId INT, pname VARCHAR(10),PRIMARY KEY (SNo));
```

I want the `Sno` to auto increment and I want the `PId` to be primary key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe show us your code and tell us which dbms you're using?

Comment: fizzi its already tagged here **mysql**

Comment: Where's the problem?

Comment: Using mysql @fizz

Comment: the problem is that it says the auto increment should be a primary key, which i dont want!

Comment: between this is my first question in this website, so happy that all these answers came so quickly, thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
         CREATE TABLE products 
          (
           SNo INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
           PId INT, 
           pname VARCHAR(10),   
           PRIMARY KEY (SNo,PId)
          );
```

Comment: As of now this is working but i don't think i am allowed to have more than one primary key in a table, will it increase the weight of the table since I have assigned two fields as primary key, if not it would be great! @Mr. Bhosale

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
`PId` INT NOT NULL,
`SNo` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`pname` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`PId`));
```

Comment: I tried this already and also typed your query, it says there can be only one column and it must be defined as a key.